# "For the sake of " in IELTS writing

Tags: word-choice, writing, ielts, writing-advice

Can I use "for the sake of" in my IELTS writing essay ? Thanks

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112166/discussion-on-question-by-nhan-nguyn-for-the-sake-of-in-ielts-writing).

Answer (score 0):

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sake has "for the sake of ..." = "for the purpose of ...".

The same source has "sake" (noun) = "help". This leads us to the implication that "for the sake of ..." = "for the (helpful, or beneficial) purpose of ...".

This construct may be used reliably.